# Do you need a bachelor's degree to get a master's degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Can you ignore the core curriculum at your university and still get into graduate school?

Comment: Question from the title: yes. Question from the body: no.

Comment: Which country is this about?

Answer (score 4):

Some universities will allow you to start just about any course if they deem your professional experience relevant. Other universities won't.

You will have to apply and, perhaps, have a meeting with a member of faculty. That is what I did anyway.

Comment: If they allow that then undergraduate experience should qualify.

Comment: They will allow what they want, but will that match want you want is a different question...

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the country. In the US it might in principle be possible because in the US degrees are not things with official legal status.

In most (all?) European countries it would not be allowed, because university degrees are something officially recognized in laws. For example, in Spain it is a legal requirement (not something that depends on the university) to have an undergraduate degree in order to enter a master's program.